# Kotlin script failing to build

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, jvm, kotlin-script

I am trying to get Kotlin scripting to work but both Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA are failing to build the project as they are unable to find the methods that are defined in the base script definition.

For a sample project, see https://github.com/sinoz/sample-kts. It includes a simple script that adds two values using an `add` method defined in the base script definition and a script template file that references said script definition.

Running gradle build:

```
~/Documents/Hobby/untitled1$ gradle build
> Task :compileKotlin FAILED
e: /home/sino/Documents/Hobby/untitled1/src/main/kotlin/me/sino/add.kts: (3, 1): Unresolved reference: add

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2, Gradle 6.8, Kotlin 1.4.10 and OpenJDK 11. Kotlin scripting used to work before until I reinstalled Linux-and Windows (So I assume there was some caching involved that allowed Kotlin scripting to continue to function).

IDEA is also *not* giving me the option to apply a new script context as it used to do. I am not sure how to do this manually as I am unable to find any documentation on it whatsoever.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how Kotlin scripts work but you defined `add` inside of a class so I guess you can only call it on an instance of that class. That's also what the error message is suggesting...

Comment: Every kotlin script extends the base script definition (which is the abstract MyScript class) thus allowing access to the `add` method the `MyScript` class script definition has defined